# Remove the necessity of Data.Map in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

Ok, I'm trying to learn haskell. Couple of times I've posted questions that has been down voted because I can't explain well what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm going to try again with a new question.

I find a piece of code that I want to modify a bit. Here it is:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Dict = M.Map String String

translate :: Dict -> [String] -> [String]
translate dict words = map trans words
  where
    trans :: String -> String
    trans w =
      case M.lookup w dict of
        (Just w') -> w'
        Nothing   -> "whatchamacallit"

testTranslation :: Dict -> IO ()
testTranslation dict = do
    print $ translate dict ["where", "is", "the", "colosseum"]

testInsertion :: Dict -> IO Dict
testInsertion dict = do
    return $ M.insert "colosseum" "colosseo" dict

main = 
    let dict = M.fromList [("where", "dove"), ("is", "e"), ("the", "il")]
    in do
          testTranslation dict
          dict'  <- testInsertion dict
          testTranslation dict'
          putStrLn "The original dictionary is unchanged:"
          testTranslation dict
```

In short: It will replace the elems ***where*** with ***dove***, ***is*** with ***e*** and e.t.c but it is using **Data.Map**.

So my question is - Is there a way to do the same thing without using **Data.Map**

Comment: The answer is: yes, there is a way without `Data.Map`. But to say how, you should tell us _why_ you don't want to use it – exercise; performance; generalisation to non-`Ord`-keys...?

Comment: It is just to prove a friend that there is another way of doing one thing.

Comment: ...and I found out that when using this library there is a conflict with the lookup prelude function operating on lists and have to put qualified in front of it to work and so on

Comment: I found this - http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=lookup but can't understand much of it. At first sight they only define the types...Could you give some more info, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lists as dictionaries. Of course, it will not be practical for big dictionaries, because the lookup is O(N).

Here is the type signature of the list lookup:

```
lookup :: Eq α => α -> [(α, β)] -> Maybe β
```

This tells the following:

> Given some item of type a and a list of tuples (a,b), the function will return Nothing or Just someb, where someb is of type b.

As you could easily find out if you played around a bit with that function in `ghci`, it will return the second value in the tuple if the first part of the tuple equals the key.

Hence:

```
lookup 42 [(1, "one"), (42, "it"), (2, "bar")]
```

should be

```
Just "it"
```

whereas

```
lookup 77 [(1, "one"), (42, "it"), (2, "bar")]
```

should be

```
Nothing
```

You can try it in GHCi and it should ot be too hard to get rid of Data.Map in your program. As far as I can see, there are just 3 small changes to do (not counting the dropping of the import).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still couldn't get it :(...How to transform  return $ M.insert "colosseum" "colosseo" dict

Comment: @NoSense `return $ ("colosseum", "colosseo") : dict`